# AppFabric Named Caches structure

Tags: appfabric

Is it possible to have an AppFabric Cache configuration where I have named caches that use some (but not all) of the servers in a cluster?

Specifically  I want to have 3 different named caches: one will expand through server 1 and 2; the second through servers 3 and 4 and the other one through 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Server 1 and 2 are physically on location A, while servers 2 and 3 are on another location B.

Is this kind of configuration viable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this - when you create a named cache you can't limit to a subset of the servers in your cluster. This is the correct design for maintaining redundancy: if you have a cache on servers 1 and 2, and server 1 goes down, you'd want your cache to move to, say, servers 2 and 4 so you maintain the caches' availability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Phil.  My idea was not having redundancy but; I have some applications on site A which are different from the ones in site B; but I also have some common apps that may be accessed through site a or b in an active/active cluster.  I wanted to be able to manage only one cache cluster but it seems I'll have to use 3 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the specific cache using regions as app fabric supports regions that are limited to machines. May be you can clone regions across servers while creating them.